# Why overflow:hidden is not working?

Tags: css, overflow

`Overflow:hidden` is not working for me. Gray box remains under the picture. I don't know whats wrong with it. I used this code from **youtube tutorial**.
If some one can help me, I will be very thankful.

```css
.main 
{
 border: 10px solid white;
 width:378;
 height:250;
 margin:50px auto;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 25px black;
 overflow:hidden;
 }

.main:hover img 
{
-webkit-transform:scale(2,2) rotate(45deg);
}

.main:hover .content 
{
-webkit-transform:translate(-383px);
}

img 
{
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform: 300ms; 
}

.content 
{ 
 width:378;
  height:250;
 background: rgba(118,115,115,0.5);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform: 300ms;
}
   
   button 
   {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:200px;
    background:black;
    border:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:white;
    font:16px tahoma;
   }
   
   button:hover {
   opacity: 0.5;
   }
```

```html
<div class="main"><img src="img/switch.jpg" height="250" width="378"><div class="content"><button>Pepe Kalvier Switches</button></div></div>
```

Comment: you should give `height` and `width` in `px` or in `%` not like `height:232` it should be like `height:232px;`

Comment: Thanks bro, I don't know how i ignore px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add values in `px` or in `%`, In your code you didn't declare a unit of measure i.e, whether you want to add `px` or `%` or `em`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kt25nehm/)**

like this:

```
.main {
   width:378px;
    height:250px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `height` and `width` with `px`  in `.main` div

```css
.main 
{
 border: 10px solid white;
 width:378px;
 height:250px;
 margin:50px auto;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 25px black;
 overflow:hidden;
  
 }

.main:hover img 
{
-webkit-transform:scale(2,2) rotate(45deg);
}

.main:hover .content 
{
-webkit-transform:translate(-383px);
}

img 
{
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform: 300ms; 
}

.content 
{ 
 width:378;
  height:250;
 background: rgba(118,115,115,0.5);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform: 300ms;
}
   
   button 
   {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:200px;
    background:black;
    border:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:white;
    font:16px tahoma;
   }
   
   button:hover {
   opacity: 0.5;
   }
```

```html
<div class="main"><img src="img/switch.jpg" height="250" width="378"><div class="content"><button>Pepe Kalvier Switches</button></div></div>
```

Comment: same code as user asked not changed that the value should be in `px` not in `232`

Answer (score 0):

```
width:378;
height:250;
```

add px, pls

Answer (score 0):

Just correct your css like this...

Your **CSS**

```
.main {
  border: 10px solid white;
  width:378;/* Your mistake is here */
  height:250;/* Your mistake is here */
  margin:50px auto;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 25px black;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Updated **CSS**

```
.main {
     border: 10px solid white;
     width:378px;
     height:250px;
     margin:50px auto;
     box-shadow:0px 0px 25px black;
     overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Now overflow is working but text on the image is not displaying. Only animation working but the text is not showing on the image when i hover my mouse.

Comment: @AliSultan which text are you saying i can't get you

Comment: Text from button. Pepe Kalvier Switches